# Carbon dates comparison and date format

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm trying the following:

I'm developing a function to compare two dates in the following format:

```
$date = "Mon Sep 14 2020 02:07:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)";
```

The function is the following (it has some extra code for my tests):

```
private function isMoreRecent($newVariation, $oldVariation) {
    // dates for testing:
    $newVariation = "Mon Sep 14 2020 02:07:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)";
    $oldVariation = "Sun Sep 13 2020 12:02:49 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)";
    // dates for testing:

    // date: 2020-09-14 02:07:25.0 UTC (+00:00)
    $newVariationFormat = $this->reformatDate($newVariation);
   

    // date: 2020-09-13 12:02:49.0 UTC (+00:00)
    $oldVariationFormat = $this->reformatDate($oldVariation);
    
    if ($newVariationFormat->toDateString() < $oldVariationFormat->toDateString()) {
        dd('holaaa');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The "reformatDate" is a function to convert our string date to a Carbon type as follows:

```
private function reformatDate($date) {
    $month = substr($date, 4, 3);
    $month = intval($this->getMonthNumber($month));
    $day = intval(substr($date, 8, 2));
    $year = intval(substr($date, 11, 4));
    $hour = substr($date, 16, 2);
    $minutes = substr($date, 19, 2);
    $seconds = substr($date, 22, 2);

    return Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

Where getMonthNumber():

```
private function getMonthNumber($month) {
    $monthKeyValues = [
        '1' => 'Jan',
        '2' => 'Feb',
        '3' => 'Mar',
        '4' => 'Apr',
        '5' => 'May',
        '6' => 'Jun',
        '7' => 'Jul',
        '8' => 'Ago',
        '9' => 'Sep',
        '10' => 'Oct',
        '11' => 'Nov',
        '12' => 'Dec',
    ];

    return array_search($month, $monthKeyValues);
}
```

it returns an object like this:

```
Carbon\Carbon @1600049245 {#255 ▼
#constructedObjectId: "0000000021e9258b000000005e04548d"
#localMonthsOverflow: null
#localYearsOverflow: null
#localStrictModeEnabled: null
#localHumanDiffOptions: null
#localToStringFormat: null
#localSerializer: null
#localMacros: null
#localGenericMacros: null
#localFormatFunction: null
#localTranslator: null
#dumpProperties: array:3 [▶]
#dumpLocale: null
date: 2020-09-14 02:07:25.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

Well I have the following question: for the two dates I'm using for testing,

```
$newVariation = "Mon Sep 14 2020 02:07:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)";
$oldVariation = "Sun Sep 13 2020 12:02:49 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)";
```

$newVariation is earlier than $oldVariation, so why:

```
if ($newVariationFormat->toDateString() < $oldVariationFormat->toDateString()) {
        dd('holaaa');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

returns me false instead true?

I've been following the Carbon documentation and according to it $newVariationFormat must be less than $oldVariationFormat.

I've also tested using lessThan, $first->lessThan($second), but the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

[EXTRAHELP]: I finally need to transform our dates to the following format:

```
'2020-08-13T16:09:22.421Z'
```

What kind of format is it?

Thanks.

Comment: I would really start with `createFromFormat`, rather than your unsophisticated `reformatDate` function.

Comment: You say "$newVariation is earlier than $oldVariation", but in your example that is not the case; $newVariation is about 14 hours _later_ than $oldVariation.

Comment: thanks for the observation, Im going to rewrite it

Comment: Cbroe, how would you use Carbon's "createFromFormat" instead of using my reformatDate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon object can also be compared with standard operators:

```
if ($newVariationFormat > $oldVariationFormat)
```

And you reformatDate can be shortened:

```
private function reformatDate($date) {
    return Carbon::parse(preg_replace('/\s+\(.*\)$/', '', $date));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recent date is greater than an earlier date. So you have to change the direction of your comparison.

Why not directly compare Carbon objects instead of converting them to strings?
Try this

```
if ($newVariationFormat->greaterThan($oldVariationFormat))
```

Previous code should normally return true;

Comment: thanks for the answer, now I see I was mistaken explaining my self, but appreciate so much your contribution "A recent date is greater than an earlier date" (too much hours in front of the computer)